# Breakpoint is not working correctly in PhpStorm+Xdebug

Tags: php, nginx, phpstorm, xdebug, ubuntu-18.04

[image]

Does anyone know why this breakpoint is like this instead of the red-colored point after I *start listening for the PHP debug connections*? This happens every time I add a breakpoint.

And every time I open a file in my Magento module this message comes:

[image]

- Latest PhpStorm
- Ubuntu 18.4
- Nginx

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. Further, you need to provide a [mcve], i.e. the recipe how you set things up or at least what information you already gathered.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to provide more information about the issue so that others can understand well. Thank you for the information and references @UlrichEckhardt

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!

1. Got to `Settings/Preferences | Language & Frameworks | PHP | Servers`
2. Select the Host (in my case it was `mow.com`)
3. Untick the checkbox for `Use path mapping (Select if there is remote or symlink are used)`